Problem with sending and receiving IR signal to enable the projector Epson
I use the Raspberry Pi 3 with the Raspbian terminal OS and work on a project that includes managing the Epson EH-TW750 projector through an IR transmitter and receiver.
I successfully used irrecord from the LIRC package to record signals from the original remote control (remote controller 219863500). However, when trying to send the recorded signal via an IR transmitter, the projector does not respond to the on-up command. I may have written incorrect codes or use the wrong format to send the signal.
Below is the result of reading the command using irrecord and the sketch that I uploaded to the Arduino
irrecord
begin remote

  name  projectproba
  bits           32
  flags SPACE_ENC|CONST_LENGTH
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  header       9038  4433
  one           593  1657
  zero          593   536
  ptrail        588
  gap          107598
  toggle_bit_mask 0x406A1616
  frequency    38000

      begin codes
          BTN_ON                   0x81C01FE0 0xCD591300
      end codes
end remote

Arduino
Protocol=NEC2 Address=0x381 Command=0xF0 Repeat gap=40200us Raw-Data=0xFF00381 32 bits LSB first
Send with: IrSender.sendNEC2(0x381, 0xF0, <numberOfRepeats>);

Protocol=NEC2 Address=0x5583 Command=0x90 Repeat gap=43650us Raw-Data=0x6F905583 32 bits LSB first
Send with: IrSender.sendNEC2(0x5583, 0x90, <numberOfRepeats>);

Has anyone faced the same problem, how did you solve it?
(some config files for lirc):
#/boot/config.txt
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=6
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=20

#/etc/lirc/hardware.conf
LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput --listen"
LOAD_MODULES=false
DRIVER="default"
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES=""

